# Self-referencing as an Apikorus

Tags: halacha, heresy, humor

I have a friend who has a habit of joking about being an apikorus (because he wears his peyos behind his ears). Beyond the strictly judgmental, is there a problem with self-referencing as an apikorus, particularly if one is known to be *fromm* (religious) and to believe in the ikarim?

Comment: I had a friend in Yeshiva who was into "nonstandard" ideas. This was met with people calling him a kofer. To which he would jokingly reply that he is a modeh bimiktzas.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is a general prohibition that one is not allowed to be self-disparaging. I haven't seen this as an actual *issur* - prohibition per se. However, there are many paragraphs in Pirkei Avot that in some way, mention that one should not do this. The two most notable that I can think of:

וְאַל תְּהִי רָשָׁע בִּפְנֵי עַצְמָךְ - Avot 2:13

Do not be a wicked person in your own eyes.

אל תהי בז לכל אדם - Avot 4:3

Do not disparage **anyone** (i.e. - including yourself. It does not say "anyone **else**")

An *apikoros*, as you know, does not receive commendations in the Talmud, or anywhere, in general, in Judaism. Self-evaluation is valuable if it is used to improve oneself. But, generally, a person should not publicize his own character faults other than for useful positive purposes. For example, if he had a flaw in the past that he has improved, it is very useful to teach others who have currently a similar flaw, his example of how he improved himself so that they learn to emulate how he improved.

Comment: Beautiful answer

Comment: This may not apply if the person is obviously joking as is the case in the question.